# programming and debugging of different sam types

Tags: debugging, cortex-m, microchip, sam

i have a curiosity nano with an ATSAMD21G17D controller as target and an ATSAMD21E18A for programming and debugging. now i want to use a different target e.g. an ATSAMC21G18A.
I think that the software on the debugger has to be changed.

Can anyone help me with this?
Is there already software for the debugger?
Is there a tool for it or can it be created with atmel studio/microchip studio or mplab x?

thanks for the help

i have connected the debugger to the new controller.

i used the programming tool from microchip studio for the 1st test.
i can select the debugger, but i can't change the controller. it still shows me ATSAMD21G17D.

when i connect, it also shows me that i have a different target.